# Dual y-axis plot using seaborn objects (v0.12)

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to make a dual y-axis plot using the new seaborn interface (seaborn.objects, available in v0.12). However, I am having difficulties getting it to work.

My first try is this:

```
import seaborn.objects as so

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y1": [5, 2, 1, 6, 2], "y2": [100, 240, 130, 570, 120]}
)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
so.Plot(df, x="x").add(so.Bar(), y="y1", ax=ax1).add(so.Line(), y="y2", ax=ax2)
```

But this will create the seaborn plot with one y-axis and an empty dual-axis plot.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm learning as I go along, but I think the following code will produce the desired graph. `so.Plot(df, x="x").add(so.Bar(), y="y1").add(so.Line(), y="y2")`

Comment: No, this is a graph with only one y-axis. I want the bar plot on the left axis, and the line plot on the right y-axis. I have edited the numbers in the original post to make it more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call [`Plot.on`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.on.html) to use pre-existing matplotlib axes:

```
import seaborn.objects as so

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y1": [5, 2, 1, 6, 2], "y2": [100, 240, 130, 570, 120]}
)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
p = so.Plot(df, x="x")
p.add(so.Bar(), y="y1").on(ax1).plot()
p.add(so.Line(), y="y2").on(ax2).plot()
```

[image]

Note that there will likely be a `Plot.twin` method to make this more natural, but it's not been implemented yet.