# Subplots with Seaborn objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to use [Seaborn objects](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) and combine it with Matplotlib functionality to create a plot where I can add annotations etc.

But the beginnings are hard. Normally one uses `ax=ax` to tie a Seaborn plot to a figure, but hard to figure that out in Seaborn Objects.

Any help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.objects as so

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 8))
fig.suptitle('1 row x 2 columns axes with no data')
# Here Seaborn object - maybe add ax=ax:
(so.Plot(df, x="Year", y="Temperature").add(so.Bar(), so.Agg(), so.Dodge()))
```

Comment: See [Dual y-axis plot using seaborn objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633213/dual-y-axis-plot-using-seaborn-objects-v0-12) pointing to `.on(...)`. For your code: `(so.Plot(df, x="Year", y="Temperature").add(so.Bar(), so.Agg()).on(ax).plot())`